# What is the purpose of partial attribute in rails render method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We can render a partial using

```
<%= render "shared/header", attr1: 1, attr2: 2 %>
```

or using the following method

```
<%= render partial: "shared/header", locals: {attr1: 1, attr2: 2} %>
```

Only the difference i have found is the way attributes are passed to the partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no big difference between them. I prefer the first example. But sometimes u should render this partial within concrete layout. And u should type `<%= render partial: "shared/header", layout: 'something'%>` . Also note that explicitly specifying `:partial` is required when passing additional options such as `:layout`. So it depends on situation. If u want to render just partial without any extra options then just use first example or use second one if u want to pass some extra options like `layout`